# How to call the method from child component to parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one method in Child component like below:

```
showAcknowledgement() {
    this.noticeService.getNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.GetUserNotice).subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.data.filter((res: any) => {
      if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
        this.noticeText = res.noticeText;
        this.noticeAttachment = res.noticeAttachement;
        this.noticeCode = res.noticeCode;
      } else if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
        this.message = [{ field: "", message: data.message[0].message }];
        this.objError = this.message;
        this.showError = true;
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    })
    });
  }
```

I need to call this method in parent component inside ngOnInit() because while page loading I need to call that method. I tried like below but its not working

Parent HTML:

```
<app-acknowledge-notice-modal #child></app-acknowledge-notice-modal>
```

Parent TS:

```
@ViewChild(AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent, {static : true}) child : AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent;


ngOnInit() {
    this.child.showAcknowledgement();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `@Output()` inside child component (https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

It's not direct method call but pretty common thing. So, in your case it could be something like this:

Parent HTML:

```
<app-acknowledge-notice-modal (someEvent)=someMethod()></app-acknowledge-notice-modal>
```

Child TS:

```
@Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

`someEvent` in parent's HTML and child's TS must match while `someMethod()` is a method inside parent's TS

Comment: I already tried this way but its not achievable

Comment: What do you mean by saying "not achievable"? Is there technical limitation, error, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

**Using Type Selector:**

*Child Component*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-acknowledge-notice-modal',
  template: <div>...</div>
})

class AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent{
showAcknowledgement() {
this.noticeService.getNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.GetUserNotice).subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.data.filter((res: any) => {
      if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
        this.noticeText = res.noticeText;
        this.noticeAttachment = res.noticeAttachement;
        this.noticeCode = res.noticeCode;
      } else if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
        this.message = [{ field: "", message: data.message[0].message }];
        this.objError = this.message;
        this.showError = true;
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
     })
    });
   }
 }
```

*Parent Component*

```
@Component({
  selector: parent-component,
  template: <app-acknowledge-notice-modal></app-acknowledge-notice-modal>,
  directives: [AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent]
})

class ParentComponent{

  @ViewChild(AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent) child: AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {        
    this.child.showAcknowledgement();
  }
}
```

**Using String Selector:**

*Child Component*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-acknowledge-notice-modal',
  template: <div>...</div>
})

class AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent{
showAcknowledgement() {
this.noticeService.getNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.GetUserNotice).subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.data.filter((res: any) => {
      if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
        this.noticeText = res.noticeText;
        this.noticeAttachment = res.noticeAttachement;
        this.noticeCode = res.noticeCode;
      } else if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
        this.message = [{ field: "", message: data.message[0].message }];
        this.objError = this.message;
        this.showError = true;
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
     })
    });
   }
 }
```

*Parent Component*

```
@Component({
  selector: parent-component,
  template: <app-acknowledge-notice-modal #child></app-acknowledge-notice-modal>,
  directives: [AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent]
})

class ParentComponent{

  @ViewChild('child') child: AcknowledgeNoticeModalComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {        
    this.child.showAcknowledgement();
  }
}
```

Comment: In my parent component, I have menu and loader code also there so I cant use string selector

Comment: @SalahuddinAhmed I'm waiting to find out too the OP results as well! You have a well documented approach and it's the one I trust as well from the angular docs.

Comment: @Salahuddin Ahmed: I tried with type selector also not working.